# 16 Honda HRV 2WD Acceleration problem

Tags: electrical, transmission, computer

The Vehicle dash lights on left side lit up and the drive, nuteral, park, and shifter light signal flashing on the dashboard, and operating properly but The Vehicle doesn't go over 40mph and won't go faster. I check the battery, charger, ignition, and accelerator and there all normal.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Page 76 of your owner's manual says that if the transmission indicator is blinking, it means that your transmission has a problem. You may get the best results by going to a transmission shop rather than a general mechanic.